# Binary predicate for `std::count_if` is not working

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, lambda, stdvector

I am currently trying to use a lambda function to `std::count_if` the sum of two consecutive elements in an array equal to a number. A sample code is given below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    const int Number = 3;
    std::vector<int> vec = {1,1,2,4,5,6};    

    auto count = std::count_if( vec.begin(), vec.end(),
    [&](int A, int B) -> bool
    {   return A+B == Number;   });

    std::cout << count << '\n';
}
```

The output should be `1`, since we have one possible case( `1 + 2` ).

However, I could not succeed. Can anybody tell me what do I miss?
Here is the error msg:

```
|234|error: no match for call to '(main()::<lambda(int, int)>) (int&)'|
```

Comment: `std::count_if` expects a function with a single parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *[@Yksisarvinen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976805/yksisarvinen)* explained, the `std::count_if` is designed for the unary predicate. Therefore the compiler can not accept the lambda, I passed.

After a while, I have found another solution to this problem. If I provide a templated function, which takes

1. iterators(i.e. start and end) of the container (on which I need to do the adjacent element check), and
2. the binary predicate, which will be used for checking adjacent relationship

that could be a more natural solution, like any other standard algorithm. **([See a live demo online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EUbhSfaQYqn8br5Y))**

```
template <typename Iterator, typename BinaryPred = std::equal_to<>>
constexpr std::size_t count_adjacent_if(
   Iterator beginIter,
   const Iterator endIter,
   const BinaryPred pred = {})
{
   if (beginIter == endIter) return 0; // nothing to do!
   std::size_t count{};
   for (Iterator nextIter{ beginIter }; ++nextIter != endIter; beginIter = nextIter)
      if (pred(*beginIter, *nextIter))
         ++count;
   return count;
}
```

and can be called like:

```
const auto count = ::count_adjacent_if(
   vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), [number](const int lhs, const int rhs) { return lhs + rhs == number; }
);
```

---

Or like [*@bipil* mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49702126/binary-predicate-for-stdcount-if-is-not-working/49702180#comment86418335_49702180), let the predicate remember the previous element. Which is less recommended, since it is a non-generic solution and needs the non-empty container. **([See a live demo online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1V6DqVkGr12GZvqq))**

```
int lhs = vec[0];
const auto count = std::count_if(vec.cbegin() + 1, vec.cend(),
   [&](const int rhs) {
   const bool condition = (lhs + rhs == number); // check for the condition
   lhs = rhs; // change the lhs = rhs (i.e. current element = next element)
   return condition; // return the condition
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that [std::count_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) uses unary predicate. What compiler tells you: "You gave me a lambda with 2 arguments, I expected lambda with one argument".

I believe what you are looking for is [std::adjacent_find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find). It compares every two adjacent elements of a container (possibly using a binary predicate).

Comment: Though adjacent_find only finds the first pair, not counts them.

Comment: Hmm, right. I'm not sure if there's any function in `<algorithm>`, that could take binary predicate for counting elements. Might require outer loop to count found occurences.

Comment: This can probably be achieved with `count_if`: 1) you define a custom iterator that dereferences to a pair of adjacent values; 2) you predicate is deeper uncurried, i.e. it accepts that pair.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen HolyBlackCat: you both are right. I tried with  `std::adjacent`_find. It will only return the first case. For the reaming I need to use a `iterator` based loop and pass the range in to the `std::adjacent()` . Anyways, thanks for the support.

Comment: Or maybe even with a stateful predicate that remembers the previous value.

Comment: You could write a template function `adjacent_count`, which would be quite similar to `std::adjacent_find`, just running it in loop and returning count of items found.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible option is to use [`std::inner_product`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product). First I'd write a little helper function:

```
#include <numeric>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>

template <typename ForwardIterator, typename BinaryPredicate>
auto count_pairs_if(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, 
                    BinaryPredicate pred)
{
    const auto n = std::distance(first, last);
    if (n < 2) return std::size_t {0};
    return std::inner_product(first, std::next(first, n - 1), std::next(first),
                              std::size_t {0}, std::plus<> {}, pred);
}

template <typename Range, typename BinaryPredicate>
auto count_pairs_if(const Range& values, BinaryPredicate pred)
{
    return count_pairs_if(std::cbegin(values), std::cend(values), pred);
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
auto count = count_pairs_if(vec, [=] (auto lhs, auto rhs) { return lhs + rhs == Number; });
```

Here's a [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/072a2f7011008f8b).